# All the planets in our solar system rotate 'Anticlockwise', except Venus. Why is the only planet that rotate' clockwise'?

Tags: angular-momentum, astrophysics, rotational-dynamics, planets, solar-system

All the planets in our solar system rotate 'Anticlockwise', except Venus. Why is the only planet that rotate 'Clockwise'?

Comment: "The four final rotation states of Venus", Alexandre C. M. Correia & Jacques Laskar, Nature 411, 767-770 (14 June 2001). I can't comment on the research, though.

Comment: Uranus rotates nor clockwise, nor anticlockwise; its axis lies nearly in its orbital plane.

Comment: But, why he have 'The four final rotation states' ?

Comment: You will have to read the paper, I am afraid, I don't have the entire text, nor the time to read it myself, right now.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7819/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25153/ , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201853/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having any experimental data at hand, I guess that most planets formed from a uniformly rotating dust disc, and thus their rotational and orbital momentum have the same sign.

However, upon random tangential impacts, some of them (Venus, Uranus..) could change their original axis of rotation, and most probably it happened so early we will not find any traces thereof.

At SE, there are multiple related discussions.