# Does the Earth spin because its surface has less mass than its core as lighter things travel faster in space?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

Would heavy elements from space hitting the Earth slow down the earth's rotation as the difference between the masses of the core and surface would be less?

Comment: More on reasons for initial spin: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23104/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12140/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You should give information about yourself on your user
page. Apparently, you know nearly nothing about physics, which is a
bit short for this site. And you should explain your assertions.
It may only be me, but I found your (wrong) explanation of greater speed for
lighter bodies interesting as it is actually based on observation.
Trying to base your knowledge on observation is good, but will not get
you very far in one lifetime. So, as Newton would say, you should also
see more and further by sitting on the shoulders of scientists who
came before you, which means some formal study of physics.

Answer (score 1):

The Earth spin because of the collisions it withstood at its early begining. One theory stipulates that it actually collided with another planet form the solar system which was going opposite direction. The collision gave birth to the moon. It also explains why the moon is always facing earth the same way.

Nevertheless, it certainly has nothing to do with the difference of mass. You may also note that heavier elements do not travel *slower*, they are simply require more energy to accelerate.

Finaly, elements hitting Earth from space could slow Earth rotation if they had the right collision course, but the probability for any given object to hit Earth in a way that would slow it down is virtually the same as the probability for a collision that would accelerate it.

Comment: Doesn't the earth spin because when it was made the particles that formed it was rotating around each other due to gravity?

Comment: Of course, but that rotation didn't originate form nowhere. A certain side of rotation must have had more kinetic energy than the other thus taking the Earth to rotate there way. It's a bit like the water in a sink. It's going to start spinning the side the more particle are moving or with the more energy. Theoretically, perfectly still water would not spin when drained. It's the same with the formation of Earth. Now if another planet collided it certainly bring a lot of kinetic energy in it's direction making Earth spin its way, but as I said, the other planet is an unconfirmed theory.

Comment: Doesn't the Moon face Earth the same way because of tidal locking? Most major moons in the Solar system are tidally locked to their planets.

Comment: Maybe it's the only reason, but I'm just saying in that theory it plays an important role. I remember reading an article which explained some other characteristics about moon orbit which were uncommon, I'll see if I can find it, but in the meanwhile, you can read about this hypothesis if you are interested:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_impact_hypothesis#Modified_hypothesis

Comment: cheers guys as i now realise that if nothing else i can ask a decent question!

Answer (score 1):

Rotation generally comes from existing [angular momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum) in the initial cloud
that increases in angular speed as the collapse into a denser body
lowers the [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia).

I do not understand what you  mean by "lighter things travel faster in
space".  It is  a strange  statement. It is known that light thinking
travels faster than heavy thoughts, but I do not think that the
properties of the [noosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noosphere) extend to matter in the physical universe.

However, that is certainly not the reason for the Earth spin as, according to
information you could have found yourself on the internet, the
core of the earth spins a bit faster (a very tiny wee bit faster) than
the outer part ([example](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/02/110220142817.htm)).

By the way, the surface of the planet does have less density than the core. To state that it has less mass, you should first make precise how deep you consider the surface to extend.

Change at the surface of the planet due to heavy matter hitting Earth
from space is however relevant. This matter does hit the planet with
some speed that could increase or decrease (very minutely) the
rotation speed over time if it were always acting in the same way.
However, increases and decreases probably average to nothing over
time. Still, by increasing the mass at the suface of the planet, it
does increase the [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) (the resistance to changes of
rotation speed of a spinning body), and hence it slows down extremely minutely over the
millions of years the Earth rotation speed (exactly for the same
reasons that the initial cloud rotated faster when collapsing into a
planet). Note that this is dependent only on the total mass falling on
the planet (and where it falls), it is not dependent on the heaviness
of each chunk, or its density.

Comment: a bit deep for me, but was thinking that from the piont of view from our own solar system the sun appears stationary. the earthe travels around the sun and the moon also travels around the earth. the distance travelled by the moon is much greater than the distance travelled by the earth and the reason it is greater is its mass is less. no? surly the same thinking can explain why bodies in space rotate. or am i missing something completely? sorry

Comment: That is an amusing observation you made. But it is a bit like saying
that people move faster than trains because, as they travel in the
train, they can move inside (say, from side to side) and hence cover
more distance in the same time. The Earth rotates (on itself) around
its center of mass. Similarly Moon and Earth rotate both around a
point that is their common center of mass, which is closer to the
heavier body in proportion of masses. Hence the Moon has to travel a
circle with a longer radius. They are both passengers of the
Earth-Moon system (train) that travels around the sun.

Comment: If you were replacing the Eath-Moon system by the moon alone on the
same orbit around the sun, it would simply follow the current path of
the Earth-Moon system exactly at the same speed (up to very tiny
approximations). The same is true for Earth alone. So the speed and
distance covered by bodies in a given time is a much more complex
issue than an inverse proportion to weight (or rather mass) of the
concerned bodies. It is however true that, for the same given impulse,
a lighter body will travel faster than a massive one, actually twice
as fast if it is half the mass.

Comment: The Earth-Moon system is like a [seesaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seesaw), with a big guy on one side and
a small guy on the other side. To balance the seesaw, the big guy must
sit closer to the axis (some seesaws actually have 2 seats on each
side) so that their common center of mass is on the axis. When balancing, the small guy far from the axis will go further
up and down than the big guy close to the axis. It is exactly the
same for Earth and Moon: the small guy (Moon) is far from the axis
(center of mass) and thus moves more when balancing the big guy
(Earth). It works like levers.

Comment: i like your "seesaw". would the fictional "heavy elements" alter the axis altering the centrifugal force? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your last question. What _centrifugal force_ ? None was considered so far. And what are the _fictional "heavy elements"_?

Comment: the "centrifugal force" acting against gravity and the "heavy elements" from the top of the page in the question.  
 

Would heavy elements from space hitting the Earth slow down the earth's rotation as the difference between the masses of the core and surface would be less?"

Comment: The centrifugal force is a consequence of the rotation. It is
orthogonal to the axis of rotation. Hits by matter on surface have no
direct effect on speed or axis of rotation as they balance on
average.  See answer.

Comment: ok thanks,but i'm still struggling with "lighter things travel faster in space" as i stated "from the piont of view from our own solar system the sun appears stationary. the earth travels around the sun and the moon also travels around the earth. the distance travelled by the moon is much greater than the distance travelled by the earth and the reason it is greater is its mass is less. no?" as this relates to any system, as the way i see it the velocity of every particle in our earth moon systen or solar system or galaxy is the same but the speed within any system depends on mass or density.

Answer (score 0):

angular momentum of particles causes the body to spin. think of ice skaters. as they pull their arms in they speed up. same goes for particles sucked in by gravity.  earth's collision with the body that formed the moon may have impacted the rotation speed. but it was already spinning.

Comment: thanks, i suppose that everything spins as there are infinatly more ways for a body to spin than not.