# How does the Earth rotate, given that the torque acting on it while revolving is zero?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, earth, planets

I've come to understand that the torque acting on the Earth while revolving the Earth is zero. Torque is the force responsible for rotation of a body. So how does the Earth rotate?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12140/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68646/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving bodies have inertia which means that they will continue to move at a constant velocity unless acted upon by an external force (this is [Newton's first law of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_first_law)).

Similarly, rotating bodies have a [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia), meaning that they will continue to rotate unless acted upon by an external force (torque).

Therefore, [torque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) is only required to either *accelerate* (or decelerate) a rotating body, or to *act against* a resistive force so as to maintain a constant rotational velocity.

Since there is only a very tiny resistance to the rotation of the earth, no torque is required. Note, however, that since there *is* resistance (primarily from tidal forces) then the earth *is* actually slowing down.