# Why is the net angular momentum of Solar system not zero?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum

Title says it all.

When we take the angular momentum of the solar system into account, we know that it is a net positive value. **From where, how and why** did our solar system acquire such a huge angular momentum?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes matter to initially rotate/spin/orbit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68646/what-causes-matter-to-initially-rotate-spin-orbit) Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178627/123208 and the links there.

Comment: you mean angular momentum about its barycenter?

Comment: this might interest you https://academic.oup.com/astrogeo/article/53/5/5.19/208905

Comment: One more question I have is that why is the rotation of planets in our solar system not opposite to the rotation of the sun? One would expect that if the planets were produced from the substance ejected from the Sun, then their rotation should have been opposite to that of the Sun.

Comment: @RobJeffries in the answers what they are stating are observational facts, but what I want to know is the explanation behind the observed phenomena.

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla You haven't read my answer then.